# Git Recent pull to a branch

Tags: git

Let's say I'm working on a branch XYZ and someone else pushes some changes in the main branch, How do I get the latest changes to my branch XYZ? I switched to dev branch and got the latest pull but when I go back to my branch XYZ I don't get the recent changes that I get in the Dev branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have not pushed yet your branch XYZ, assuming that XYZ was created from dev:

```
git checkout dev
git pull
git checkout XYZ
git rebase dev
```

That will replay your local commits on top of the updated dev.

If XYZ was alreay pushed, then it is more prudent to do a simple merge.

```
git checkout XYZ
git merge dev
```

Comment: Why does it matter whether XYZ is pushed or not? Don't you always have the choice to merge or rebase anyway? (Also, I find I shortcut the checkout-pull-checkout-merge using `git pull; git merge origin/dev` to avoid having to switch branches, when I don't care if my local `dev` is up to date)

Comment: @Amadan rebase change the SHA1 of the commits, so if they were already pushed, that would involve a push --force and a communication to colleagues. I agree on your shortcut, I was just trying to keep that answer simple for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge your `dev` branch into your branch `XYZ` like this:

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
# to get your branch up to date with the remote

git checkout XYZ
git pull origin XYZ
# to get your branch up to date with the remote

git merge dev 
# this will merge your dev branch into your branch XYZ.
# there could be possible "merge conflicts" resolve it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this

```
git checkout xyz

git pull origin xyz
git merge main_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so even without switching branches. Switching is slow if there are a lot of new changes on dev. Be careful though - with this process you have to be sure you pushed all the local hanges you previously made on dev.

```
# get latest commit from dev branch whilst still being on XYZ
git fetch origin dev:dev
# merge those changes
git merge dev
```